# Update parent record when child update by configuration?

Tags: configuration

I have one parent Object - Position and one Child Object - Candidate. Both object have Picklist field called Status.
Child - Status - selected,rejected 
Parent - status - Open,Closed

relationship is Lookup relationship

If 10 child records created with status Value Selected, Then Parent record status value should be update with closed value

I know how to write the code for this. but I need to configuration steps to achieve this Can any one help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic use case for [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries), which allows you to build Roll-Up Summary Fields against a Lookup relationship.

If you're not able to use DLRS, you'll have to write a moderately complex trigger against Candidate. Since you need to handle delete events to maintain an accurate rollup, Process Builder and Flow are not a candidate solution.

Your trigger would need to fire on insert, update, and delete, accumulate a set of Position objects related to the changed Candidates, and then run a bulkified helper method to query the full set of Candidates related to the Positions and update their statuses accordingly. A SOQL aggregate query would probably serve this purpose nicely, unless there's other logic you haven't discussed.